# Issues with CORBA communication

Tags: java, linux, solaris, corba

This maybe too localized, but I am hoping someone can help me articulate my questions properly.

So, we have a front end web server that communicates with a back end app server using CORBA. I have been asked to port the back end application to a LINUX box, which I did. But, in order to test it, I am trying to point the front end web server to the LINUX back end.

We are using omniORB-4.1.4, and here is how the instance of the back end system is obtained:

```
        String args[] = new String[0];
        System.out.println(getDateTime()+"Instance: Connecting to: "+initialHost+"  "+initialPort+"  "+enviornment+"  "+version);
        java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
        props.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", initialPort);
        props.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", initialHost);
        props.put("com.sun.CORBA.giop.ORBGIOPVersion", "1.0");
        orb=org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(args,props);
```

When both and front end and back end are running on a SUN/Solaris box, it seems to get an instance fine. But, when the back end is running on a LINUX box, it gives a Connection Refused exception, and the hostname as 127.0.0.1

```
  2012/10/22 13:53:22.033   EvaluateInstance: Connecting to: cmrheldv  23026  DEV87  0871
   Oct 22, 2012 1:53:22 PM com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl <init>
  WARNING: "IOP00410201: (COMM_FAILURE) Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: cmrheldv; port: 23026"
 org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
    at      com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2200)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.connectFailure(ORBUtilSystemException.java:2221)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:205)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:218)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.createConnection(SocketOrChannelContactInfoImpl.java:101)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.request(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.invoke(BootstrapResolverImpl.java:74)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.BootstrapResolverImpl.resolve(BootstrapResolverImpl.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:22)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:22)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.resolver.CompositeResolverImpl.resolve(CompositeResolverImpl.java:22)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl.resolve_initial_references(ORBImpl.java:1151)
    at EvaluateInstance.InitializeModules(EvaluateInstance.java:152)
    at EvaluateInstance.initializeVariables(EvaluateInstance.java:326)
    at EvaluateCF.initializeInstances(EvaluateCF.java:1792)
    at EvaluateCF.processRequest(EvaluateCF.java:112)
    at coldfusion.tagext.CfxTag.doStartTag(CfxTag.java:102)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
    at cfconfglobalconstants2ecfm330318830._factor9(/opt/jrun4/servers/or_dev87/cfusion-ear/cfusion-war/origenate/confglobalconstants.cfm:372)
    at cfconfglobalconstants2ecfm330318830._factor10(/opt/jrun4/servers/or_dev87/cfusion-ear/cfusion-war/origenate/confglobalconstants.cfm:13)
    at cfconfglobalconstants2ecfm330318830._factor11(/opt/jrun4/servers/or_dev87/cfusion-ear/cfusion-war/origenate/confglobalconstants.cfm:6)
    at cfconfglobalconstants2ecfm330318830.runPage(/opt/jrun4/servers/or_dev87/cfusion-ear/cfusion-war/origenate/confglobalconstants.cfm:1)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
    at cfapp_globals2ecfm1890385339.runPage(/opt/jrun4/servers/or_dev87/cfusion-ear/cfusion-war/origenate/app_globals.cfm:61)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
    at cfapp_locals2ecfm610494134.runPage(/opt/jrun4/servers/or_dev87/cfusion-ear/cfusion-war/origenate/securitycontrol/app_locals.cfm:49)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
    at cfdefault2ecfm129406838._factor9(/opt/jrun4/servers/or_dev87/cfusion-ear/cfusion-war/origenate/securitycontrol/default.cfm:107)
    at cfdefault2ecfm129406838.runPage(/opt/jrun4/servers/or_dev87/cfusion-ear/cfusion-war/origenate/securitycontrol/default.cfm:1)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:381)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:79)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.http.WebService.invokeRunnable(WebService.java:172)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
 Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:500)
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:146)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(DefaultSocketFactoryImpl.java:60)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.<init>(SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.java:188)
    ... 64 more
```

Is it something to do with the properties? Because the two boxes can hear each other perfectly well on the defined ports.

Also, when I do a netstat on the Linux box, it shows up a LISTENING connection to the port from the Solaris box. What makes the response return as a 127.0.0.1?

The Solaris box is called yyyy, and the Linux box is called xxxx. The initial port and host is gotten through an ini file.

Comment: So, you don't show where you get 'initialHost', 'initialPort', etc. that you use to populate the connection properties. Is that where you're seeing the localhost address? The error message that you posted shows a hostname of 'cmap03'. So, I'm confused. Can provide more detail? By the way, you may have some luck setting the inital connection parameters as Java system variables in addition to passing them as a map to the init method.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek Re your last point, I don't see why that would help. The search order is defined in the Javadoc for org.omg.CORBA.ORB and it includes both system properties and the ORB initial properties.

Comment: @EJP - not sure about omniOrb, but I've seen other situations where this has resolved the issue. Simple thing to try - if it doesn't work, not much time will have been invested in trying it.

Comment: @roymustang86 I suspect somewhere else you have a COSNaming or possibly JNDI lookup that uses 'localhost' instead of the new hostname.

Comment: So, I have updated the error message. When it tried to get a connection to cmrheldv, it gets a connection refused exception and the return address is 127.0.0.1

Comment: SO, I found out what the problem was: http://jeewesley.blogspot.com/ I just had to change the /etc/hosts file

Comment: You should post this as the answer then so that other will benefit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was nothing to do with the code. It was something to do with connectivity.

On the LINUX box, cmrheldv, I had to edit the /etc/hosts file and change the 127.0.0.1 to the real ip for the localhost.

http://jeewesley.blogspot.com/2008/12/glassfish-ejb3-remote-interface-on.html

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the path to your variable and start orbd.

Open cmd and type:

```
set path=%path%;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin"
```

After that:

```
start orbd
```

Answer (score 2):

You should first start the ORB port with this command :

```
orbd -ORBInitialPort [PORT NUMBER]
```