# javax.naming.NamingException: Couldn't connect to the specified host : Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE

Tags: java, weblogic, cluster-computing, corba

I have implemented clustering  for our application in weblogic 10.3.6 environment.
I have created two managed server and one standalone server which is used as a proxy server.

But my problem is when I login to the application or searching through any parameter in my app, it doesn't allow me to proceed further and throws the following exception.

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Couldn't connect to the specified host : Connection refused: connect [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: Co
used: connect  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No]
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.Utils.wrapNamingException(Utils.java:83)
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ORBHelper.getORBReferenceWithRetry(ORBHelper.java:656)
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ORBHelper.getORBReference(ORBHelper.java:594)
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.InitialContextFactoryImpl.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactoryImpl.java:85)
        at weblogic.factories.iiop.iiopEnvironmentFactory.getInitialContext(iiopEnvironmentFactory.java:33)
        at weblogic.factories.iiop.iiopEnvironmentFactory.getInitialContext(iiopEnvironmentFactory.java:71)
        at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:315)
        at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:285)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
        at Utils.RequestProcessor.AuthorisationRequestProcessor.LookUp(AuthorisationRequestProcessor.java:72)
        at Utils.RequestProcessor.AuthorisationRequestProcessor.checkUser(AuthorisationRequestProcessor.java:151)
        at Utils.RequestProcessor.AuthorisationRequestProcessor.processPreprocess(AuthorisationRequestProcessor.java:237)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:173)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at org.ajaxanywhere.AAFilter.doFilter(AAFilter.java:46)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: Connection refused: connect  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
        at weblogic.iiop.Utils.mapToCORBAException(Utils.java:886)
        at weblogic.iiop.IORManager.locateNameService(IORManager.java:213)
        at weblogic.iiop.IORManager.createInitialReference(IORManager.java:123)
        at weblogic.corba.orb.ORB.string_to_object(ORB.java:341)
        at weblogic.corba.orb.ORB.resolve_initial_references(ORB.java:235)
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ORBHelper.getORBReferenceWithRetry(ORBHelper.java:631)
        ... 35 more
```

Comment: How have you connected the two? (config)

Comment: I have just created a cluster and added two managed server as listen address

Comment: Have you seen these questions with a similar error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633790/error-when-trying-to-connect-to-jacorb-naming-service http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017782/issues-with-corba-communication